# How to fully bypass `error: no match for ‘operator==’`?

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault, std

I am using a program called [`SlideSort`](https://github.com/iskana/SlideSort), which does not compile anymore on a recent Debian system using GCC 6.3.0. Instead, it throws the following error:

```
mstree.cpp:228:11: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}’ and ‘long int’)
   if(dFile==NULL){
           ^
```

Not being a C programmer, I tried to bypass the problem by gently telling the compiler that the code is old; in my understanding this is roughly what  GCC's option `-std=c++98` does.  (See in GitHub's [issue tracker](https://github.com/iskana/SlideSort/issues/1) for the patch to the Makefile).

Then the code compiles. but it segfaults in some corner cases (Test data and command available in GitHub's [issue tracker](https://github.com/iskana/SlideSort/issues/1)).  The same test command works fine when the program is compiled with GCC 4.9.4.

Thus, passing `-std=c++98` to GCC was either not enough or a wrong idea altogether.  Is there an alternative to either compile on an old system or updated the code to the latest standards (which I can not do by myself) ?

Comment: If its a pointer why not dFile == nullptr

Comment: *but it segfaults in some corner cases* -- Probably caused by the overuse of `malloc` instead of simply using `vector`, and also out-of-bounds array accesses.  It is basically `C` code with just a sprinkling of C++.  Changing to `vector` and using `vector::at()` may identify where the problems exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ 98 the streams used to have an `operator void*()` to check the stream state. It returned a null pointer when the stream was in an error state. Turned out that this implicit conversion caused some unexpected results when accidentally invoked in odd places.

So in C++11, which gained explicit operators, it was turned into an [`explicit operator bool()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) instead. This returns `true` for a good state and `false` when the stream is in a failed state.

Being `explicit` it can also only be used in places where a `bool` is expected. This removes most of the unexpected conversions from the old operator.

So `if(dFile==NULL)`, testing for a non-good state of the stream, is now written `if (!dFile)`.

And actually, the tests `if (dfile)` (good state) and `if (!dFile)` (non-good state) have always worked. The comparison against `NULL` has never been required, it just happened to work when the operator returned a `void*`.

Comment: `if (!dFile)` was always a valid test - it was before C++11, and still is now.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know why this code ever worked. In no version of the C++ standard is a scalar stream object comparable to an integer *or* to `nullptr_t`. That being said, your question is not how to fix the code you've found but how to bypass the error. **I do not recommend doing what I'm about to say here in production code.** It's a hack, and it's only designed to get an unusual library like this working.

The `==` operator can be defined outside of any class, as a standalone function. The library you're using compares `std::ofstream` to `long int`. Let's make that comparison valid.

```
bool operator==(const std::ofstream&, long int) {
  return false;
}
```

Now your code will compile. But it will probably run incorrectly. You could try making the comparison smarter by having it check whether the `std::ofstream` is truthy.

```
bool operator==(const std::ofstream& out, long int n) {
  return (bool)out == (bool)n;
}
```

Now it's a bit smarter. But there's no silver bullet here. The code you were given is *not working and not standard C++*, so there's no fullproof way to get it working without changing the actual library code. So my suggestion is to fork the repository and fix the broken line of code yourself.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is this (`if(dFile==NULL){`) if condition is trying to check whether a file was open successfully for writing, if so you use function `is_open` which is available in c++. So simply replace the condition by `if (dFile.is_open())`. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the rest of the code, you can just try to rephrase that line such as:
if(!dFile)

See what happens next.